# jquery ui (v1.8.20) dialog - destroy not remove added ui element and not return the element back to its original position

Tags: jquery-ui

From what I read, the `$(#selector).dialog("destroy")` is supposed to remove all the added `jquery ui` elements and return the element, the dialog attached to, back to its original `DOM` position.  I wrote a test html and it is not doing either.  In firebug, after I clicked close, it simply makes it becomes invisible (`display:none`).  Am I doing something wrong?  Below is my test html:

```
<html> 
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .modalDialogPopup {
            display:none;
            border:1px solid #4f8cc5;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="/resources/default/1_0/js/jquery.js?v=081814" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/resources/default/1_0/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js?v=081814" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script>
        var testPopUp = {
            popUpID : '#testPopUp',
            close:  
                function() {
                    $(this.popUpID).dialog("close");
                },
            open:       
                function() {
                    $(this.popUpID).dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: 'Test Outer Pop Up',
                        dialogClass:'modalDialogPopup',
                        resizable: true,
                        close: function( event, ui ) {
                            $(this.popUpID).dialog( "destroy" );
                            alert('outer Pop Up Destroyed?  '+$(testPopUp.popUpID).attr("class"));
                        }
                    });
                    $(this.popUpID).dialog("open"); 
                }
            }
        $(document).ready(function() {
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="OuterDiv">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="testPopUp.open(); return false;" >Open PopUp</a>
        <div id="testPopUp" class="modalDialogPopup">
            <div id="testPopUpDiv" style="overflow: auto; display: table;">
                <div id="testPopUpContent" >
                    This is a Pop Up Test
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="testPopUp.close(); return false;" >Close PopUp</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you put this in a jsFiddle and run jsHint on it?

Comment: put it in jsFiddle and it didn't really do anything.  http://jsfiddle.net/ymbacjfj/

Answer (score 0):

Found two problems that cause the destroy to not working:

1) on this line ==>

```
close: function( event, ui ) {$(this.popUpID).dialog( "destroy" );
```

I shouldn't use this.popUpID.  It should be testPopUp.popUpID, like below,

```
close: function( event, ui ) {$(testPopUp.popUpID).dialog( "destroy" );
```

Once I did that, it starts to remove all the added jquery ui elements.  But it still does not put the element (id="testPopUp") back to it's original DOM position, which is resolved after I done #2 below.

2) Change my jquery ui version to jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js.